# Select ALL shapes on a powerpoint slide, and get all data back to Excel VBA to eventually change the text of those shapes

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

Below is a code that allows you to select a shape, then it populates cells in Excel by giving shape name, content, slide number, and commentary (for your personal notes).  BUT instead of selecting one shape at a time, I would like to select ALL or more than one shape at a time to populate back to the Excel sheet.

Can anyone help?

Here is the code:

```
Dim ppapp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim pppres As PowerPoint.Presentation

Sub getshapedata()
On Error GoTo line1
Set ppapp = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.application")
Set pppres = ppapp.ActivePresentation

Dim shapeslide
Dim shapename
Dim shapetext
Dim nextrow

shapeslide = ppapp.ActiveWindow.View.Slide.SlideIndex
shapename = ppapp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Name
shapetext = pppres.Slides(shapeslide).Shapes(shapename).TextEffect.Text
friendlyname = InputBox("Insert Friendly Name for " & shapetext, "Friendly Name", "")

nextrow = Sheet1.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

Sheet1.Range("a" & nextrow) = shapeslide
Sheet1.Range("b" & nextrow) = shapename
Sheet1.Range("c" & nextrow) = shapetext
Sheet1.Range("d" & nextrow) = friendlyname

Exit Sub



line1:
MsgBox "No item selected"

End Sub

Sub writedata()
Dim c As Object
Dim shapeslide
Dim shapename
Dim shapetext

Set ppapp = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.application")
Set pppres = ppapp.ActivePresentation

For Each c In Sheet1.Range("a2:a" & Sheet1.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

shapeslide = Sheet1.Range("a" & c.Row)
shapename = Sheet1.Range("b" & c.Row)
shapetext = Sheet1.Range("c" & c.Row).Text
friendlyname = Sheet1.Range("d" & c.Row)
pppres.Slides(shapeslide).Shapes(shapename).TextEffect.Text = shapetext

Next c

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a `Slide` variable and a `Shape` variable to use as an iterator:

```
Dim ppSlide as Object 'PowerPoint.Slide
Dim ppShape as Object 'PowerPoint.Shape
```

Then set it to your slide:

```
Set ppSlide = ppapp.ActiveWindow.View.Slide
```

Then, iterate over the shapes collection on that slide:

```
For each pptShape in ppSlide.Shapes
    If ppShape.HasTextFrame Then
        '### DO STUFF
    End If
Next
```

In your code, something like below, as amended with the custom function `GetPPTSelection`, based on the comment:

> I don't want ALL the shapes to write back to excel, only the ones I select. How do I go about doing that?

The function `GetPPTSelection` returns a Collection of shapes (if any are selected) and I think it should handled "Grouped" shapes, as well as multiple selections, and also ignores shapes which don't have a `TextFrame` (embedded images, etc.)

```
Sub getshapedata()

    Dim ppSlide As Object 'PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim ppShape As Object 'PowerPoint.Shape
    Dim nextrow As Long

    Set ppapp = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.application")
    Set pppres = ppapp.ActivePresentation
    Set ppSlide = ppapp.ActiveWindow.View.Slide

    For each ppShape in GetPPTSelection(ppPres.Windows(1))
        friendlyname = InputBox("Insert Friendly Name for " & shapetext, "Friendly Name", "")
        With Sheet1
            nextrow = .Range("a" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            .Range("a" & nextrow) = ppSlide.SlideIndex
            .Range("b" & nextrow) = ppShape.Name
            .Range("c" & nextrow) = ppShape.TextEffect.Text
            .Range("d" & nextrow) = friendlyname
        End With
    Next
Exit Sub


Function GetPPTSelection(window As Object)

' Returns a Collection of selected shapes, if shapes are selected
' Returns a Nothing, if anything else (slides, text, etc.) selected
Dim coll As New Collection
Dim c As Integer
Dim s As Integer
Dim g As Integer

Dim sel As Object '# PowerPoint.Selection

Const ppSelectionShapes As Long = 2  ' in case of late binding

Set sel = window.Selection

If sel.Type = ppSelectionShapes Then
    For s = 1 To sel.ShapeRange.Count
        If IsGrouped(sel.ShapeRange(s)) Then
            '# handle grouped shapes
            For g = 1 To sel.ShapeRange(s).GroupItems.Count
                coll.Add sel.ShapeRange(s).GroupItems(g)
            Next
        Else:
            '# ordinary, ungrouped shapes:
            coll.Add sel.ShapeRange(s)
        End If
    Next
End If

'# Get rid of any shapes which don't have a textframe:
For c = coll.Count To 1 Step -1
    If Not coll(c).HasTextFrame Then coll.Remove (c)
Next

'# Return the collection to the calling procedure:
Set GetPPTSelection = coll

End Function

Function IsGrouped(shp As Object)
'Returns boolean if shape is groupshapes
Dim ret As Boolean

On Error Resume Next
ret = shp.GroupItems.Count > 1
IsGrouped = ret

End Function
```

I got rid of the `On Error GoTo Line1` because there is no label `Line1` in this code, also, I think it's generally better to anticipate and trap errors, rather than using a catchall like that which tends to make debugging *real* problems that much more difficult. If this code is still raising some errors, let me know which line and I can try to help debug it.

Or, just use `On Error Resume Next` at your own peril :)

Comment: Thanks David! However, when I put the code in, and take the error handling out, I get the error "This member can only be accessed for a single shape". The line highlighted is `shapetext = ppShape.TextEffect.Text`

Comment: You have grouped shapes on the slide?

Comment: That was it!.  Also, I don't want ALL the shapes to write back to excel, only the ones I select.  How do I go about doing that?

Comment: Ok I know how to do that but I'm on mobile right now let me get back to you in an hour or two :)

Comment: OK, I made some revisions to the answer. Good luck!

Comment: Hey David, thanks for your help. There seems to be a couple snags! the 10th line `shapeslide =` is giving me a syntax error.  Also in the function it states `IsGrouped` is undefined.  Thank you for your help, I am certain this is exactly what I need though!

Comment: Crud I forgot to include that function I'll update it a little later

Comment: Sorry for the delay in confirmation of the code.  I still ran into some snags.  I was trying to see if I could figure this out on my own but to no avail.  I changed 'Exit Sub' to 'End Sub' as it was giving me an "expected end sub" error. (line before the function).  Then when I select data on the powerpoint slide, and run the code it selects the line `Dim sel As PowerPoint.Selection` and says "Compile Error:  User-defined type not defined".  I couldn't figure it out :(  Thanks so much for your help so far btw

Comment: You're using late-binding, so declare that `As Object`.  (Alternatively, add explicit reference to the PowerPoint object model)

Comment: Thanks. But now it says "Object doesn't support this property or method" for `Set sel = window.Selection`

Comment: OK, the function is already *receiving* the `Windows(1).Selection`, which must have been leftover from when I was testing on my end. Try `For each ppShape in GetPPTSelection(ppPres.Windows(1))` instead, in the `getShapeData` procedure (revised answer above).